# Can't get rounded corners of row in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rounded-corners

I'm developing an android app and I'm using recyclerview. I've managed to display rows with data and apply design to them, except I can not get rounded corners for rows. Bellow are my `xml` files.

File with name `rounded_corners_cards.xml` for rounded corners:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/grayLight"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

File for rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/StandardListRow"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_cards">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/offer_picture"
        style="@style/StyleRowIcon"
        android:contentDescription="@string/card_offer_image"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried to change `rounded_corners_cards.xml` file but without luck.

The result is on the image bellow:
[image]

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Could you please add a picture of the result you get?

Comment: I've updated question and added screenshot.

Comment: add your style file.I am testing sth and I doubt the width and the height.

Answer (score 6):

By far the simplest way to get rounded corners on a layout is to wrap it with a `CardView`. Normally, this will *also* display a shadow, but you can turn that off by using the `cardElevation` attribute.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/StandardListRow"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/offer_picture"
        style="@style/StyleRowIcon"
        android:contentDescription="@string/card_offer_image"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Note: this will only work on Lollipop+

> Due to expensive nature of rounded corner clipping, on platforms before Lollipop, CardView does not clip its children that intersect with rounded corners.

Comment: I've tried this and I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: THANKS FOR THE GREAT TIP from every iOS programmer in the world!  :)   so easy on droid

Answer (score 0):

The most simple approach as mentioned is use of cardView https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html

just use this as your RecyclerView item XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:contentPadding="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/offer_picture"
         style="@style/StyleRowIcon"
         android:contentDescription="@string/card_offer_image"
         android:scaleType="centerInside" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE**:- cardCornerRadius is the element which defines roundness in the card the higher the dp, the more rounded it is.